# How to count discord.py reactions (without counting up!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My bot sends a message and reacts with various emojis. Now I want to count how many people have clicked on a specific emoji.

If the bot was offline in the meantime, it should also work, so I would save the current result in a file, but also means that he should'nt just count up.

The current code is that it checks the Message ID from a reaction. At the point he should get the result.

```
# if message is known and should be retrieved
if Found is not None:

    # Get the number of a specific reaction
```

Comment: As mentioned above, the bot should also be offline (code must begin at "async def on_reaction_add) between and not just count up. No duplicate! :(

Comment: Could you elaborate? How is this not covered by `{react.emoji: react.count for react in message.reactions}`?

Comment: I don't understand the code and it doesn't work, perhaps because I use the rewrite version as I have now found.

Comment: Now I know the solution for my problem after testing: reaction.count
This can always be retrieved if the message ID has been saved.